# Prevent Microsoft Access to lock MSSQL View Serverside?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access

I've got an MSSQL Server, which is providing some Views to a specific Userrole.

On this Views the Role has just the right to `SELECT`.

For some reason, while an User of this Role is connected to this View through Microsoft Access, its impossible to Change the View (like adding a column etc.).

When I kill the User (actually not him personally, just his `SELECT`-process) everything works fine again.

I know there are ways inside Access to change that, but:

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour serverside?

Comment: Are you running this select statement via the ADO method?

Comment: This may be of interest http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.515190.14

Comment: Its ODBC SQL Server i chose on Access @Matt Donnan

Comment: Looks promising, the WITH(NOLOCK) would be a good answer I suppose...
@Remou

Comment: @Harry I take it from that, you are using linked tables to MSSQL and using the Access query designer for your statements. You're probably better not to have linked tables at all. For select statements you can use the "pass-thru" query approach so MSSQL will do the work and avoid the locks. Any other interaction with the tables could be done via ADO recordsets, these have pessimistic locking options etc

Comment: @MattDonnan thnx for this information. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I use `WITH (NOLOCK)` at the end of the dataset in the `FROM` clause for my application and it works well.